# hidutil stopped working on macOS 14.2 update

Tags: macos, sonoma

I've got the following command to run on every macOS start:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x700000064, "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000035}]}'
```

It always rebinds a key (`non_us_backslash` to `grave_accent_and_tilde`) on my international Apple Magic Keyboard to a convenient one to match with my us keyboard laptop.

Right after 14.2 install this command stopped working. It throws no error, the `hidutil property --get UserKeyMapping` prints out some kind a valid output as follow, but the key behaviour isn't updates after the command run as it appears before update. Also I'm not sure that in the past the --get argument output was printed out as a Decimal rather than hex. But this is as it is now.

The command output:

```
(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771125;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771172;
    }
)
```

### UPD 2024.01.17:

I've got the answer from Apple on my issue about that.

They said that the problem is fixed.

I've tried to reproduce it on my laptop and it persists, yet it gets with a lower severity, as now (as the one mentioned somewhere above) binding starts working but after replugging the device. I can add that this is true for a wireless devices as well. My binding started working after I reenabled Bluetooth. This fix worked for me a few times in the row, so I consider it as a persistent.

Nonetheless I've objected Apple's claim that the issue has been solved. So let's see what's happens next.

Comment: This started happening to me as well when I updated to Ventura 13.6.3 last night.

Comment: It seems that this is a bug in their updates then, and that this was a shared code snippet that was included in both of the releases, since your update was minor one I speculate that it was a hot fix of some bug.

Comment: Created radar for this but http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5611459140648960

Comment: I noticed it suddenly returned working after one or few deep hibernations (power unplugged). And keep working until a reboot. I rebooted twice and succeeded twice after it.

Related thought: In past (before the OS update to 13.6.3) the mapping sometimes was stopping working after some deep hibernations so I had to re-run hidutil after it. I find it related (one bug reveals to fix another one).

Comment: hidutil key remapping stopped working for me with Ventura 13.6.3 last week.

Comment: @kirikaza didn't get the second part of your comment, had it worked those two times after the first one breaker reboot? And if yes, have you done something special in those successful reboots towards the unsuccessful one?

Comment: There are few reports and trackers to the problem (like this one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255340598?sortBy=best), but nothing emerged yet. I had to go back to Karabiner as an alternative solution, works on Sonoma: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Comment: I too went back to Karabiner Elements as an alternative solution for now.

Comment: @YaroslavL sorry, I meant I rebooted, hidutil didn't work, then after one or two deep hibernations, it returned working and was working until the next reboot, then I rebooted, hidutil stopped working again, and after a deep hibernation it returned working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding MacOS 14.3 where `hidutil` is already fixed. You need to run `hidutil` as sudo as mentioned above, so in case you launch it as an agent, you put your launch `*.plist` into `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` with chmod to root and `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.hidutil.plist`

Comment: Thanks. That restores the full capabilities of this utility as it was before. Although I would not close the radare issue to Apple until they responses something concrete on it.

Comment: One more thing to add. On 14.3 version bindings falls off after each wireless keyboard disconnecting (e.g. when using laptop in an another place). So at least in my case the command still has to be run manually on each keyboard reconnection.

Comment: @YaroslavL try to find out whether you can still have a trigger on the keyboard connect event. Use this trigger to re-run the binding.

Comment: Other thing is to try to bind per device id.

```
`/usr/bin/hidutil property --matching '{"ProductID":YourProductID,"VendorID":YourVendorID}' --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000039,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000003B}]}'`

Comment: @SerhiKrachko, Yep, this is exactly the command that I'm using having this behavior. So just for a matter of experiment will try to rebind it globally (without --matching)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reports and trackers to the problem (like this one: [`hidutil` stopped working on macOS 14.2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255340598?sortBy=best), but nothing emerged yet.

I had to go back to [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) as an alternative solution, which works on Sonoma.

There are some quirks in starting it, see [Driver alert keeps showing up](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/troubleshooting/driver-alert-keeps-showing-up/)

Also you need to add `karabiner_observer` (in my case: `/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/bin/karabiner_observer`) to **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Input Monitoring**

Comment: Hmm, I don't have `/org.pqrs` in my `Application Support` dir (or anything related to Karabiner).

Comment: Just to mention the report that you're referencing to is mine as well.

Comment: An interesting detail regarding this: I installed and started Karabiner, gave it permission, etc. Then without adding any remapping I noticed that my old hidutil mapping had started working again. If I kill Karabiner it stops again. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step-by-step guide.

1. Make sure that you have upgraded your Mac to 14.3+
2. Run next command to create a new list file, which will run as a Daemon:
   `sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hidutilKeyMapping.tilde.plist`
3. Paste the next lines and save the file to map **§** key to **`** key.

```
    <!-- place in /Library/LaunchDaemons and run sudo launchctl start com.hidutilKeyMapping -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.hidutilKeyMapping</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/usr/bin/sudo</string>
          <string>/usr/bin/hidutil</string>
          <string>property</string>
          <string>--set</string>
          <string>{
            "UserKeyMapping": [
                {
                  "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x700000064,
                  "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000035
                }
            ]
          }</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </plist>
```

For different key settings you can use [hidutil-generator](https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/).

4. Run this command to give execute permissions: `sudo chmod 755 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hidutilKeyMapping.tilde.plist`
5. As the last step run this to install your hidutil daemon to run on start: `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hidutilKeyMapping.tilde.plist` If you see an error, try unloading first by running `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hidutilKeyMapping.tilde.plist`
6. Restart your Mac and viola!

Answer (score 2):

I was tired of waiting for Apple to fix it, and I figured that Hammerspoon was a bit simpler to setup than Karabiner, so I created the following to make it even easier to achieve the same results:

https://gist.github.com/maurofaccenda/aca92d695220e545c5e7ffd28dc365c4

Answer (score 0):

Updated to 14.3, the problem no longer persists as long as you have hidutil run as root (e.g. sudo) as per:

- [run hidutil w/ sudo](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/18g4vxn/comment/kj67g64/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

ps make sure you are using the correct ProductID / VendorID...i noticed mine had changed w/ the update.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/345161)